# CSS text transform problems

Tags: css, rotation, transform, text-rendering, rendering-engine

This question has been asked many times here but i haven't found a good solution to the problem. Some suggested to add backface-visibility: hidden with all the declination of prefixes but has not solved the problem for me nor the suggestion to use font-smoothing: antialiased did he trick.
I'm asking if someone has recently figured it out how to render a CSS rotated text in a pretty way, without the text appears to be mangled.

[image: css rotated text problem in FF24]

http://jsfiddle.net/pBtEW/10/

```
<div>
    <p class="rotated">this text is rotated</p>
    <p class="notrotated">this text is not rotated</p>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="submit1" class="rotated"/><br/>
<input type="submit" id="submit2" class="notrotated"/>

.rotated {
    transform:rotate(-4deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-4deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-4deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-4deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-4deg);
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I believe this is up to browser's (and possibly hardware's) mercy...to me Opera Presto seem to handle better than Chrome/Firefox (on this low end machine I'm using). Also, I think it would be better to put non-prefixed version at the last, not at beginning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried to put the non-prefixed version at the end but the result is the same :-/
FYI machine is running x64Win7, i7, 4GB RAM, ATIm HD5800

Comment: The point of putting non-prefix version last is that CSS rules are parsed from top to bottom, so for a browser that both support non-prefixed and prefixed versions, putting non-prefixed version at the end would guarantee that [the latest rendering method (i.e. not "backward-compatible method", if that exist)](http://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/) is used. And for your question, I want to say that Chrome and Firefox renders WAY worse than your screenshot on my old XP computer...

Answer (score 0):

With 315 degree rotated text on my website, I have used the font-family:courier with line-height:100% and font-style:normal as an acceptable cross browser solution for my purposes. A second best solution (text rendered perfectly on IE and Mozilla but not perfect in Chrome) was to not set a font-family.